# How to fix ClassNotLoaded exception Java

Tags: java, exception

Im dealing with a `ClassNotLoaded exception` and I dont know how to solve this. According to google and other topics I have read, this seems to be an issue of Eclipse debug functionality.

The scenario is the following: Working with **JavaMail**, when I try to retrieve the messages from an email account, SOMETIMES the console shows this:

> "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException:
>   com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred
>   while retrieving component type of array".

Comment: You need to provide more detail about your project setup.  Also the parts of the code that cause the exception should help people to provide answers.  The question from Karna's comment serves as an example.

Comment: I have checked Karna answered. Could you please provide some example code in order to load the class in the code?